# Night sky when man-made light sources are made obsolete. Would the night sky still be affected by light-pollution?

Tags: technology, space

Im creating a world where for whatever reason all power on Earth is gone. Meaning there is no more man-made light. Which also means no more light pollution. Would the night sky revert to its former glory before light pollution? Or would the night sky remain the same as it is currently?

Comment: man was making light with fire long before electricity.

Comment: It's difficult to make as much light using fire as using electricity. A large reason why we have so much light pollution is because we *can*. Without some good reason to need light all night long, most fires will probably be burning out before midnight.

Comment: Of course not, the damage from light pollution has been done, why would it simply go away if we stop adding to it, obviously we'd have to do some clean up first if we want the old night sky back.

Comment: To give some context to the downvotes: you are basically asking "when I switch off the light in my room at night, does the room goes obscure or not?".

Answer (score 4):

In the absence of artificial lights, the night sky would revert to the completely black with millions of stars that you can still see in some remote places today.

Comment: Yes basicly correct. It might take a few days for smog etc to clear but then your right.

Comment: @Slarty : & smog has what to do with light pollution? nothing, so what are you talking about?

Comment: Well already it has nothing to do with light pollution but dust and small particles in a range of sizes produced from all manner of human activity would not aid visability

Comment: There are only about 6,000 to 8,000 stars visible with the naked eye from Earth's surface, and only a bit less than half of them can be visible at any one time at a single spot.

Answer (score 3):

"Light pollution" is caused entirely by lights on the ground reflecting off stuff in the atmosphere; there's nothing durable or lasting about it.  As soon as the light sources are removed it goes away, so you'll be able to see the full night sky.

Answer (score 1):

yes, light pollution would be greatly reduced if artificial lights were gone. However, it also depends on the level of air pollution: thick smoke (like in some cities in China) could also obscure faint stars from view.